# stat command in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, command-line-arguments, stat

I'm trying to get a formatted time output using a such command in Mac OS X 10.7.5 (in the Terminal app):

```
stat -f "%m" -t "%Y" "myfilename.jpg"
```

However, it still gives me a unixtime, not the formatted string:

```
1349690206
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `S` for string output.

```
$ stat -f %Sm -t %Y file.txt
2012
```